# Is current time between X and Y time with Moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Possibly a really simple solution that I'm over complicating.

I've got a start time and an end time in the "HH:mm" format.  ie "22:07"

What I'm trying to do is figure out if the current time, is between those hours.

```
const compare = moment("15:47", "HH:mm")
const until = moment("08:00", "HH:mm")

console.log(moment().isBetween(compare, until))
```

The above logs out false, even though it is currentl 18:09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is not provided with the time, moment created the 'momentified' date with the current date. As a result, the `until` could be lesser than your `compare` date. 
You could check for the difference between those to be negative and add a day to your `until` date as follows -

```
  const start = moment("15:47", "HH:mm")
  const until = moment("08:00", "HH:mm")

  var diff  = moment.duration(until.diff(start)).asMinutes();

  if(diff < 0){
   until.add(1, 'days');
  }
```

Check and run the snippet below to see the results (Note: I have added jQuery as well for ease of demo)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 const start = moment("15:47", "HH:mm")
  const until = moment("08:00", "HH:mm")
  $('#date1').html(start.toString());
  $('#date2').html(until.toString());
  var diff  = moment.duration(until.diff(start)).asMinutes();
  $('#date3').html(diff);
  $('#date4').html(moment().isBetween(start, until).toString());
  if(diff < 0){
   until.add(1, 'days');
  }
  
  $('#date5').html(start.toString());
  $('#date6').html(until.toString());
  $('#date7').html(moment().isBetween(start, until).toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="date1"></div>
<div id="date2"></div>
<div id="date3"></div>
<div id="date4"></div>
<div id="date5"></div>
<div id="date6"></div>
<div id="date7"></div>
```

Comment: This looks like it does the trick.  The diff part is the key.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect `moment("15:47", "HH:mm")` and `moment("08:00", "HH:mm")`, you'll see that `moment` tacks on the current date. The second date therefore comes *before* the first, so you're really asking "is this time between 8 AM and 3:47 PM today?" 18:09, or 6:09 PM is *not* between those dates.

If you want `moment("08:00", "HH:mm")` to stand for "8 AM tomorrow" instead of "8 AM today," you'll have to change the way you're creating that value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do you:

```
const moment = require('moment');

function isBetween( dt, tmFrom, tmThru ) {
    const ticks     = dt.asMilliseconds();
    const ticksFrom = moment.duration(tmFrom).asMilliseconds();
    const ticksThru = moment.duration(tmThru).asMilliseconds();

    return ticks >= ticksFrom && ticks <= ticksThru;
}

const isBetween9and5 = isBetween( moment(), '09:00', '17:00' );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just subtract both `compare` and `until` (`const diff = until - compare`) you'll get the difference in milliseconds. Then, `moment(diff).format("HH:mm:ss")` to have in HH:mm:ss.